# Capybara. Как проверить текущий URI или Path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Добрый день. Приложение на Rails 5. В проекте **не** используется RSpec. Нужно с помощью Capybara отловить текущий адрес(url или path) и проверить его.
Есть метод current_path, который возвращает относительно корня домена его "http-адрес". Но в тесте нужно проверить верен ли текущий путь\адрес какому-то определенному, то есть после редиректа я хочу проверять верно ли он (редирект) сработал с помощью сравнивания current_path и верного пути, куда пользователь должен был попасть. Если не равен, то тест должен провалиться. Есть ли такой метод в Capybara, **как это сделать в RSpec уже нашел, но его в проекте использовать нельзя, это требование.**

Comment: *как это сделать в RSpec уже нашел* -- допишите в вопрос тогда.

Comment: Как это сделать методами  Capybara, не используя RSpec?

Comment: Допишите, что нашли.

Comment: нашел решение:
https://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_equal